# Possible sub-optimal selection sort

Tags: java, beginner, sorting

Why is this code "bad"? In all of the selection sort codes I am learning from, they do it much differently. I will learn the proper code from the book, but I would love to know why this particular code is bad.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {8, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0};
        System.out.println("The sorted array is: ");
        displayArray(selectionSort(array));
    }

    public static int[] selectionSort(int[] list) {
        int[] result = list;

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
                if (result[i] > result[j]) {
                    int temp = result[i];
                    result[i] = result[j];
                    result[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void displayArray(int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println(list[i]);
            else
                System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My question refers to the selectionSort method, but I took the opportunity to post some more in case anything else is amiss.

Comment: What do you mean by "bad"?  Does it not work properly?

Comment: It's very different from the book.

Answer (score 2):

### Too many swaps

The "standard" selection sort finds the minimum element and swaps the first element with the minimum element once per loop. In total there should be N swaps. Your version of selection sort can swap up to (N^2)/2 times.

### Unnecessary variable

I'm not sure why you use the variable `result` and return it.  You can just operate on the array that is passed in (`list`) directly.  When I first read your code I thought you were making a copy of the array, because you had this extraneous variable.

### The "standard" selection sort

Here is an example of a "standard" selection sort:

```java
public static void selectionSort(int[] list)
{
    int len = list.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        int smallestIndex = i;
        int smallestValue = list[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (list[j] < smallestValue) {
                smallestIndex = j;
                smallestValue = list[j];
            }
        }
        if (smallestIndex != i) {
            list[smallestIndex] = list[i];
            list[i] = smallestValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very concise answer! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Where is he making a copy?

Comment: @FDinoff You're right.  I just read "result" and saw that it was returned and assumed he was returning a copy.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sorting

This code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
        if (result[i] > result[j]) {
            int temp = result[i];
            result[i] = result[j];
            result[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Is not how [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) works. At first glance it looks like [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), but considering how it actually works, it looks more like a form of "ping-pong sort" (yes, I just made that up).

So, how does your current code work?

I added a little output whenever two elements were swapped and this was the results of the first swaps:

```
[8, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0] --> [3, 8, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0] (flipped 0 and 1)
[3, 8, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0] --> [2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 0] (flipped 0 and 5)
[2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 0] --> [0, 8, 5, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2] (flipped 0 and 9)
[0, 8, 5, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2] --> [0, 5, 8, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2] (flipped 1 and 2)
[0, 5, 8, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2] --> [0, 3, 8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 6, 8, 2] (flipped 1 and 5)
[0, 3, 8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 6, 8, 2] --> [0, 2, 8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 6, 8, 3] (flipped 1 and 9)
[0, 2, 8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 6, 8, 3] --> [0, 2, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 6, 8, 3] (flipped 2 and 3)
```

As you can see, whenever a new minimum value has been found, it swaps the current index value with that new minimum value. At the third flip for example, the 2 is moved to the *end* of the array, even though it should (and will, eventually) end up at index 1. Therefore, pretty much *all* elements will sooner or later be at the last index, so they are moved back and forth quite a bit, hence I am calling it "ping-pong sort".

#### Class Name

```
public class Main {
```

Would be better named as `SelectionSort` (or `SomeOtherSort` as it isn't real SelectionSort - yet).

#### Braces, and toString

Your `displayArray` method lacks some braces. It is recommended to always use braces. Even for one-liners.

You should also know, even though the methods don't work exactly the same, that there is a `Arrays.toString` method to convert any array to a good string representation.

Comment: I thought it was a bubble sort too at first, but actually it isn't.  It doesn't swap adjacent elements.  It swaps the first element repeatedly with smaller elements to its right.

Comment: @JS1 You're right, it wasn't. Good observation. I edited a bit and showed how it actually works. I am giving it the name "ping-pong sort".